Existing Australian ETA after acquiring a new citizenship
My girlfriend has a citizenship of an ETA (Subclass 601) eligible country and a valid ETA for her passport. Now she acquired a new citizenship (also an ETA eligible country if that matters) in addition to the old one and will then receive a passport for that new citizenship very soon.
My question is, does she need to reapply for a new ETA even though she still has the original citizenship, and the passport she applied for the ETA with is still valid?
It seems that e.g. an application for the US ESTA has to be filed again in this situation, however unfortunately I haven't found anything on what to do about the Australian ETA.

Have you tried asking on the Australian Home Affairs website?

I checked the popular questions section there, also tried the "ask a question" function which is essentially a bot that doesn't seem to know the answer. The only option to have a live chat with a human seems to be calling an Australian number - I admit I haven't done that and asked here hoping that I'm not the first one with this issue.
